# Parse: Creating a New Class Programmatically

Tags: class, parse-platform, schema, command-line-interface

Is it possible to create a new Class programmatically (i.e. not from the dashboard) via any of the API's or the Parse CLI?

The REST API appears to have functionality to fetch, modify and delete individual Schemas (classes) but not to add them. (https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#schemas).

Hoping for something like the following:

```
curl -X ADD \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXX" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: XXXXXXXX" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://api.parse.com/1/schemas/City
```

Comment: I don't know about REST API for parse but in my experience of using iPhone SDK of Parse, adding an object to class which does not exist on Parse backend, first creates a class on backend and then saves the object to it. So I suppose it can be done programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have skipped the part which deals with adding schema in the documentation. To create a new class, [according to documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#schema-adding-a-schema), You use following method in cURL:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: Your APP Id" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: Your master key" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d ' 
    {
      "className": "Your Class name goes here", 
      "fields": {
        "Your field name here": {
          "type": "Your field's data type e.g. String, Int etc. Add multiple fields if you want"
        }
      }
    }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/schemas/[Your class name]
```

Or in Python:

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/schemas/Game', json.dumps({
       "className":"[Your class name]","fields":{"Your field name":{"type":"your field's data type"} }
     }), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "7Lo3U5Ei75dragCphTineRMoCfwD7UJjd1apkPKX",
       "X-Parse-Master-Key": "ssOXw9z1ni1unx8tW5iuaHCmhIObOn4nSW9GHj5W",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

Comment: I was previously getting an error saying the referenced class name did not exist, just tried it again and it worked. Must've been making a silly mistake, thanks for your help.